# Tomcat 7.0.42 Neo4j 1.9.2 LifecycleException

Tags: java, tomcat, neo4j

I am running Tomcat. All is good and well, i can see the http://myserver.com:8080 page. I have java 1.6 installed on the server.

Neo4j 1.9.2 throws this error

```
Sep 6, 2013 9:34:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class MyContextListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager@41e3a0ec' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:281)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:207)
    at database.DatabaseInterface.<init>(DatabaseInterface.java:106)
    at MyContextListener.contextInitialized(MyContextListener.java:11)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager@41e3a0ec' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:259)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Unable to start TM, active tx log file[usr/share/neo4j/graph.db/tm_tx_log.1] not found.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.openLog(TxManager.java:737)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.start(TxManager.java:138)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
    ... 21 more
```

I really have no idea what is wrong. I have set ownership and permissions correctly on the store neo4j uses.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all logs under neo4j, and everything worked as a charm.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you were missing some files, so your solution should work if you don't mind losing that data.